# combining two id's that do different things to one div button

Tags: html, css

ok so the thing here is , the only way i can get the password_photo_galleries to go where they need to be is adding an extra button on the navbar to open that info.. what im trying to do is have the navbar button MyGallery bring up both photo_galleries, and password_photo_galleries, but i can't seem to figure out how to get it to combine with that one button.. any help would be much appreciated,  i also just thought about something, the only way i can think it might work is make the button My Gallery do a drop down with two buttons My Gallery / Password Gallery but my navbar is -90deg so i dont know how that would work  , but just a thought.. either way will work fine.. thanks again

```
#profile_photo_galleries .heading {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:38px;
  color:#FF00FF;
  font-weight:normal;
  border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

#profile_password_photo_galleries .heading {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:38px;
  color:#FF00FF;
  font-weight:normal;
  border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

#profile_photo_galleries {
  width:400px;
  height:600px;
  color:#000000;
  font-family:"Baskerville Old Face",serif;
  font-style:italic;
  font-size:20px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,255);
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  right:-1200px;
  padding:40px;
  transition:left 0 ease-in-out;
}

#profile_password_photo_galleries {
  width:400px;
  height:600px;
  color:#000000;
  font-family:"Baskerville Old Face",serif;
  font-style:italic;
  font-size:20px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,255);
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  right:-1200px;
  padding:40px;
  transition:left 0 ease-in-out;
}

#profile_photo_galleries:target {
  right:80%;
  margin-right:-520px;
}

#profile_password_photo_galleries:target {
  right:80%;
  margin-right:-520px;
}

.photo_gallery {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:96.9%;
  margin-bottom:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:99;
}

.password_photo_galleries {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:96.9%;
  margin-bottom:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:99;
}

.photo_gallery .heading,.password_photo_galleries .heading {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:38px;
  font-weight:normal;
  border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.password_photo_galleries .heading {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:38px;
  font-weight:normal;
  border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.photo_gallery .images a,.password_photo_galleries .images a {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  border:5px solid #000;
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.password_photo_galleries .images a {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  border:5px solid #000;
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.photo_gallery_preview,.password_photo_galleries_preview {
  border:1px solid #333;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:20px 15px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:#000;
}

.password_photo_galleries_preview {
  border:1px solid #333;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:20px 15px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:#000;
}

.photo_gallery_name a,.password_photo_galleries_name a {
  color:#FFF;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  display:block;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.password_photo_galleries_name a {
  color:#FFF;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  display:block;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.photo_gallery_link {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}

.password_photo_galleries_link {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}

.photo_gallery_count {
  font-style:italic;
  color:#666;
}

.password_photo_galleries {
  font-style:italic;
  color:#666;
}
```

HTML CODE FOR THE NAVBAR

```
<div id="right_menu">
    <a href="#profile_photo_galleries"><span>my gallery</span></a>
    <a href="#profile_password_photo_galleries"><span>Password</span</a>***this is the one i would like to open up with just the button my gallery or if you could make a drop down for a rotation -90deg span for my nav bar that would be awesome****
</div>
```

here is the navbar , no links

```
#right_menu {
  position:fixed;
  font-size:15px;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:#FF00FF;
  width:50px;
  height:100%;
}

#right_menu a {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  height:15%;
  width:50px;
  margin-bottom:0;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  position:relative;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(1) {
  background-color:#FF00FF;
  color:#FFF;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(1) span {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:-40px;
  width:130px;
  color:#FFF;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  transition:left .3s ease;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(1):hover span {
  left:-45px;
}
```

Comment: try `id='home_page'` etc - `#` represents an id in css and isn't needed in an `href` - in an `href` it links to a section of a page which is something different

Comment: exactly its linking it to a section of the page and bringing it out

Comment: it seems your css is using the href contents to style? this won't work, though it won't effect the functionality of your links

Comment: its not a link bro, its a navbar which opens up a div ease in out on the page is all

Comment: i added the code for the navbar if that helps

Comment: ah ok, the css in the first section is styling the page sections, not the HTML in the second section, I get you :-)

Comment: yeah , haha ,,,, im thinking the only way to do this is add a drop down menu on the navbar to select either password or regular gallery, 
because in the html its selecting only the regular gallery and not the password gallery because the css code is coding with different id , and i can't change that id code otherwise it wont work, unless there is a way to correspond both id codes on that one button on the nav bar

Comment: @ToniLeigh  each photo_galleries and password_galleries,  will show up side by side depending how i code the positioning , so when clicking My Gallery on the NavBar both sections which show up side by side as  boxes to click and bring up the photos, there is a lot more coding to this, but i figured all the style and everything was irrelevant to my question, and im having trouble because i dont remember if it was possible to combine both id's to one div button on the MenuBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every DOM element has a single id. you could approximate it using something like this

```
<div id='id1'><span id='id2'></span></div>
```

and then use navigation to get what you really want.